# How can search same string with PHP

Tags: php, string, search

search text in string but I try not complete.

I want search "2"($word) in string $a

```
$a = "1,22,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
$word = "2";
```

I try code below (not complete)

```
if(similar_text($a,$word))
{ echo "Found.<br>"; }
else { echo "Not Found.<br>"; }


if(strchr($a,$word))
{ echo "Found.<br>"; }
else { echo "Not Found.<br>"; }

if(strpos($a,$word))
{ echo "Found.<br>"; }
else { echo "Not Found.<br>"; }
```

Comment: Split the string into an array, then use `in_array()`.

Comment: so what do you expect then? whats the question/problem?

Comment: `var_dump(preg_match('/(^|,)' . preg_quote($word) . '(,|$)/', $a, $matches));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to search the exact `2`, then suppose you could explode them first, then `in_array()` just like @barmar has said.

```
$a = "1,22,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
$word = "2";
$a = explode(',', $a);
if(in_array($word, $a)) {
    // Found!
    echo "$word is found in \$a";
} else {
    // sorry not found
    echo "$word is NOT found in \$a";
}
```